# DllNotFoundException in NDK Android app using Xamarin

Tags: android, c++, xamarin, android-ndk

I want to make an Android app that uses NDK with C++

I made a new Android App solution in Xamarin Studio called ndkTest. I added a folder jni, and in there added these files:

- Android.mk
- Application.mk
- my.h
- test.cpp

Here are the contents of each:

**Android.mk** :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ndkTest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := my

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Application.mk** :

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

**my.h** :

```
#ifndef __MY_H__
#define __MY_H__

#define MY_CONST    1

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
short
my_func( short          my_param );

#endif /* __MY_H__ */
```

**test.cpp**:

```
// test.cpp
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <memory.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

#include "my.h"

#define SOME_CONST     2*MY_CONST
short  some_short;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

static void static_func_0()
{
some_short = 0;
}

static void static_func_1()
{
some_short = 1;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

static void static_print()
{
printf("static_print\n");
printf("some_short = %d\n", some_short);
}

extern "C" short getSomeShort()
{
printf("myExtern\n");
return some_short;
}
```

---

Here's where it gets interesting:
I have ndk installed and properly configured. In the command line, I cd to project directory and run

```
ndk-build
```

And I get this error:

```
make.exe: *** No rule to make target [path to ndk]/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/test.cpp', needed byobj/local/armeabi/objs/ndkTest/test.o'. Stop.
```

That's weird, but whatever, I can specify the full path to test.cpp in Android.mk and it builds:

```
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: ndkTest <= test.cpp
[armeabi] SharedLibrary : libndkTest.so
[armeabi] Install : libndkTest.so => libs/armeabi/libndkTest.so
```

So now I have the .so file. After adding this to top of MainActivity.cs : `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` I added this:

```
[DllImport("libndkTest", EntryPoint="getSomeShort")]
static extern short getSomeShort();
```

And I added a call to that in OnCreate. I'm getting a `DllNotFoundException`.
What am I missing?

Comment: 1) Are you adding `libndkTest.so` to your project with a build action of `AndroidNativeLibrary`? 2) Are you testing on an `armeabi-v7a` device?

Comment: When you add the so file to your project it needs to be within a folder called lib, and another folder of the device type. lib/armeabi/yourlib.so
If you're running on an emulator their device types tend to be x86
Edit your application makefile to include "APP_ABI := armeabi armabi-v7a x86" to build all the relevant so files

Comment: armeabi would be redundant when building for armeabi-v7a, unless the OP plans on testing on a phone from 2009 or so.

Comment: Good comments all. Yes, I forgot to mention that I added the .so file to the project. I'm testing on a Samsung Galaxy S6 on Android 6.0.1, a Kyocera Torque on Android 4.1.2, and a Sonim S7 on Android 4.4.2. @SushiHangover, Good point on specifying the build action of `AndroidNativeLibary` - I forgot to do that, and now it works on the Kyocera and the Sonim, but not the Samsung. When testing on the Samsung, I'm still getting the `DllNotFoundException`

Comment: @dstrube For Galaxy S6, you will need to include `arm64-v8a` ABIs

Comment: Hmm, I tried changing that line in `Application.mk` from `APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a` to `APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a` and reran ndk-build and rebuilt the app in Xamarin Studio; still getting the `DllNotFoundException`. I also tried setting the line to just this: `APP_ABI := arm64-v8a` ; same result.

Comment: Also, oddly enough, after making that change to the `Application.mk`, it still ran fine on the Kyocera and Sonim for a few times. I thought it may be using some cached version of the binary from the `lib` folder, so I removed it, cleaned the project, regenerated the `libndkTest.so`, then it stopped working. Fine, that's to be expected if I supply the wrong ABI in the `Application.mk`. BUT, when I changed the ABI back to armeabi-v7a and ran thru the same rigmarole (remove the .so, clean the project, generate the .so, add it to the project*, build the project), now it doesn't work on any device.

Comment: *: specifying the build action of the .so file to `AndroidNativeLibary` too, of course.

Comment: 1) Can you download `Native Libs Monitor` - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xh.nativelibsmonitor.app&hl=en (To ensure your `.so` is deployed to the proper architecture?)

2) Secondly, I would highly recommend reading this article for any gotcha's with regards to `.so` files: http://ph0b.com/android-abis-and-so-files/

3) Finally, can you try using `EmbeddedNativeLibrary` as using `AndroidNativeLibrary` expects you to provide the `.so` at runtime IIRC. Check #1 first before doing this. I don't think this would make a huge difference.

Comment: Jon, thanks for the suggestions. 1) I installed the app, but it didn't do much good. It verified that the .so is there, but didn't give any insight as to why my app thinks it isn't.  2) A very interesting read. Didn't lead me directly the answer, but it was certainly educational. 3) That didn't work as Xamarin Studio only accepts this option if it is a Library project. But I greatly appreciate the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround:

In Xamarin Studio, go to Project Options, Build, Android Build, and in the Advanced tab, uncheck all the Supported ABIs except armeabi-v7a. For some reason, the app doesn't work on a Samsung S6 using arm64-v8a, even though it clearly should.

YMMV

Answer (score 0):

If I had to take a guess I'd say you should rename libndkTest to ndkTest in your DllImport statement.

```
[DllImport("ndkTest")]
static extern short getSomeShort();
```

I can't currently test your version but it was working for me this way.

And I assume you've already done it but you should double check your library build action and location, it should be under lib/your_abi/your_lib.so. I remember banging my head for 2 days because of a sniffing path error...